# spring mvc 3 + jquery + AJAX + $.get - value not returned from controller to callback method

Tags: javascript, ajax, spring, jquery, spring-mvc

I am new to AJAX and currently learning to use it with Spring MVC. I am facing issues on the same.

Before proceeding to the actual real time requirement that I am working on, I am testing out the whole AJAX+Spring MVC+jquery combination with something really basic to get my understanding right.

I am having a search box+'submit' button on a page. I am sending a hard coded text to the Spring controller on submit using $.get. Then I am sending another text from that controller back to the callback function and trying to display the returned text in the callback function using an 'alert' box. This doesn't seem to work.

I see that the call back function is being called(since the 'alert' inside the callback function is being fired) so I am kind of assuming that control is being transferred to the controller and back to the callback method but I am not able to figure out why the text that is returned from the controller is not showing up on the alert box in the call back method. Not sure what I am missing here to capture the return value in the call back method.

Your response and help on this is really appreciated.

Thanks.

HTML for text box and submit button:

```
    <div class = "searchcontactform">
      <form id = "searchcontactform" name="searchcontactform" method="GET">
        <input type = 'text' size='25' name = "searchlastname" id = "searchlastname" value='Enter Last Name to Search'/>
        <input type = "submit" value="Find">
      </form>
   </div>
```

JavaScript that triggers on submit of the above form:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/resources/scripts/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(document).ready(function( ) {
    $('#searchcontactform').submit(function(){

         $.get("ContactList-JPA/search", {textsent : 'Hello Controller'},callback);

         function callback(textreceived){
               alert('In Callback. Text Received is: '+textreceived);
         };
    });
    });
```

Controller:

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
        public @ResponseBody String searchcontact(@RequestParam(value="textsent") String textsent){
        return textsent;
        }
```

Jackson Dependency in POM.xml:

```
           <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.7.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

Annotation driven in servlet-context.xml and root-context.xml:

```
    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

first of all, put `return false` at the end of submit event handler

```
$('#searchcontactform').submit(function(){

         $.get("ContactList-JPA/search", 
         {
             textsent : 'Hello Controller'
         },
         function(textreceived){
               alert('In Callback. Text Received is: '+textreceived);
         });
         return false;
    });
```

if this does not work try using Google Chrome you could debug your javascript application, put a breakpoint inside the callback and at the `$.get` line

Comment: the `return false` will prevent the default submit behaviour

Comment: This worked!. Adding the 'return false;' statement at the end of submit event handler solved my issue! Thanks so much for your response. It is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the issue is that you are returning type String and for some reason Spring/Jackson doesn't like when converting to a response. To fix the issue what you should do is the following:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/search", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody List<String> searchcontact(@RequestParam(value="textsent") String textsent){
    return Arrays.asList( new String[] { textsent } );
}
```

It's not ideal and is quite annoying. I haven't really looked into why this happens though as the workaround was fine for me at the time.

UPDATE: Apologies I'm wrong here, you are not assuming the return is going to be JSON at all so making the controller change will have no impact.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the data returned to the callback as a parameter:

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
    $('#searchcontactform').submit(function(){

        $.get("ContactList-JPA/search", {textsent : 'Hello Controller'},
           function(data){
              callback(data);
        });

        function callback(textreceived){
           alert('In Callback. Text Received is: '+textreceived);
        };
    });
});
```

You could also setup your callback function as an anonymous function to tidy things up.

```
$(document).ready(function( ) {
    $('#searchcontactform').submit(function(){

        $.get("ContactList-JPA/search", {textsent : 'Hello Controller'},
           function(data){
              alert('In Callback. Text Received is: '+data);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Then where does your callback method receive the value for textreceived

Comment: yes it has a parameter, but when you call the function you do not pass a parameter, so when you alert the parameter it does not contain a value.

Comment: checkout the jquery documentation, you will see a bunch of $.get() examples: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/86y7d/ this is javascript, learn something about it, you can give a function as parameter and expect a parameter when it is called

Comment: @melanke were those comments for me?  So your saying data is passed to callback regardless?

Comment: yes, it is for you. the $.get expect as parameter a String of URL, a data object as HTTP REQUEST PARAM and the last one is a function for callback, this function could be declared on the fly as anonynous function like you showed or an named function like I showed

Comment: @melanke thanks for the insight.  I have been using jquery for quite awhile and didn't know it passed the response back to the named callback

Comment: well this is possible for all javascript functions callback, not only for jquery :)